# How to align my search box to the center?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to put my search box in the centre like the links above it but adding :align=> "center" is clearly wrong...  here's what I have...

```
<h2 align="center"><%= link_to "List by Topic", topics_path %></h2>
<h2 align="center"><%= link_to "List by Organisation", hospitals_path %></h2>
<h2 align="center"><%= link_to "List by Country", countries_path %></h2>
<h2 align="center"><%= link_to "List by Specialty", specialties_path %></h2>

<%= form_tag guidelines_path, :class => 'navbar-search',:onSubmit=>"clearText(this)",:method => :get do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'search-query input-medium', :placeholder=>"Search", :ONFOCUS=>"clearDefault(this)" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Use: style="text-align: center;" in the tag

Comment: Ew, don't use inline styles. That makes editing a nightmare. Styles go into Stylesheets, HTML goes into an HTML file and Javascript goes into a JS file, everything is easy to move around and edit.

Comment: yes you are right.  I'm trying to do it in the stylesheet but cannot get the box to budge.  Surely text-align won't affect the actual search box itself?

Comment: ok, have sort it with text-align:center.  It was due to my confusion re css overrides - all sorted, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing an `"align"` attribute as those have been deprecated from the HTML standard - instead look to using CSS for aligning text.

That being said, if you put an `text-align: center;` property on a parent element it should align all of the children that aren't full width and accept alignment.

**EDIT**

Here is the CSS that I used to "match" (assuming I matched what you've got since I can't see your result).

```
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.search-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

form.navbar-search {
    float: none;
}
```

And you can check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx2rV/